# How to toggle block mouse or keyboard input

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, windows-services, mouse

I want to block the keyboard input and the mouse input (different methods) with an option to unblock.
I am programming a service (Console Application with the TopShelf package to use it as a service)

I googled and searched over YouTube and checked on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me (because everything is for winforms)

Comment: what do you mean by "lock?"

Comment: By lock do you mean that you are looking to disable the ability to use the keyboard and mouse inputs? If so you are going to face the reality that you won't be able to prevent the user from escaping your application via ctrl+alt+del

Comment: Yes, I mean to disable the ability to use the keyboard and mouse inputs. I tried a lot of things but they don't work and almost all of them only work for win32 and I need for win64 (they use the user32 dll)